# Java applet open network sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, applet, japplet

So i made this simple JApplet and tried to open a socket and write to it, but i got an exception saying i don't have permission???

So then i looked at this: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html

I've got the jar signed, and that's it. I don't get what to do after that????

And in the html file, what does

```
<param name=file value="/etc/inet/hosts">
```

do?

Are there any easier ways to sign japplets?

Let me ask this simply. How do i let my applet open a socket on lets say port 80 for google.com?

Comment: Last time i checked, applets couldnt communicate with nothing but their base, meaning that you can communicate to the server that serve the applet and nothing else.

Comment: @memo *"Last time i checked"*  Check again.  A trusted applet can communicate with any server that accepts connections.

Comment: Will the applet be hosted on the same server it is attempting to connect to?

Comment: BTW *"I don't get what to do after that????"* Only put question marks after questions (that is not a question), and then only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<param name=file value="/etc/inet/hosts">
```

This means that the name 'file' will have the value `/etc/inet/hosts` when queried by the applet.  E.G.

```
// in the init() method ..
String fileValue = getParameter("file");
// fileValue now has the value '/etc/inet/hosts'
```